# Thanos-Query/Query-Frontend does not show any metrics

Tags: kubernetes, bitnami, helm3, thanos, kube-prometheus-stack

Basically, I had installed Prometheues-Grafana from the [kube-prometheus-stack](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus) using the provided helm chart repo [prometheus-community](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack)

```
# helm repo add prometheus-community https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts
# helm install kube-prometheus-stack prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack
```

They are working fine.

But the problem I am facing now is integrating **Thanos** with this existing **kube-prometheus-stack**.

I installed thanos from the [bitnami helm chart repo](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/thanos)

```
# helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
# helm install thanos bitnami/thanos
```

I can load the Thanos Query Frontend GUI, but no metrics showing there.

[image: thanos metrics]
[image: thanos store]

I am struggling now to get it worked properly. Is it because of Thanos from a completely different helm chart and Prometheus-operator-grafana stack from another helm chart ?.

My Kubernetes cluster on AWS has been created using Kops. And, I use Gitlab pipeline and helm to deploy apps to the cluster.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not enough to simply install them, you need to **integrate** `prometheus` with `thanos`.

Below I'll describe all steps you need to perform to get the result.

First short theory. The most common approach to integrate them is to use `thanos sidecar` container for `prometheus` pod. You can read more [here](https://www.infracloud.io/blogs/prometheus-ha-thanos-sidecar-receiver/).

**How this is done:**

(considering that installation is clean, it can be easily deleted and reinstalled from the scratch).

1. Get `thanos sidecar` added to the `prometheus` pod.

Pull `kube-prometheus-stack` chart:

```
$ helm pull prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack --untar
```

You will have a folder with a chart. You need to modify `values.yaml`, two parts to be precise:

```
# Enable thanosService
prometheus:
  thanosService:
    enabled: true # by default it's set to false

# Add spec for thanos sidecar
prometheus:
  prometheusSpec:
    thanos:
      image: "quay.io/thanos/thanos:v0.24.0"
      version: "v0.24.0"
```

Keep in mind, this feature is still experimental:

> ```
> ## This section is experimental, it may change significantly without deprecation notice in any release.
> ## This is experimental and may change significantly without backward compatibility in any release.
> ## ref: https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/main/Documentation/api.md#thanosspec
> ```

Once it's done, install the `prometheus` chart with edited `values.yaml`:

```
$ helm install prometheus . -n prometheus --create-namespace # installed in prometheus namespace
```

And check that sidecar is deployed as well:

```
$ kubectl get pods -n prometheus | grep prometheus-0
prometheus-prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus-0       3/3     Running   0          67s
```

It should be 3 containers running (by default it's 2). You can inspect it in more details with `kubectl describe` command.

2. Setup `thanos` chart and deploy it.

Pull the `thanos` chart:

```
$ helm pull bitnami/thanos --untar
```

Edit `values.yaml`:

```
query:
  dnsDiscovery:
    enabled: true
    sidecarsService: "prometheus-kube-prometheus-thanos-discovery" # service which was created before
    sidecarsNamespace: "prometheus" # namespace where prometheus is deployed
```

Save and install this chart with edited `values.yaml`:

```
$ helm install thanos . -n thanos --create-namespace
```

Check that it works:

```
$ kubectl logs thanos-query-xxxxxxxxx-yyyyy -n thanos
```

We are interested in this line:

```
level=info ts=2022-02-24T15:32:41.418475238Z caller=endpointset.go:349 component=endpointset msg="adding new sidecar with [storeAPI rulesAPI exemplarsAPI targetsAPI MetricMetadataAPI]" address=10.44.1.213:10901 extLset="{prometheus=\"prometheus/prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus\", prometheus_replica=\"prometheus-prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus-0\"}"
```

3. Now go to the UI and see that metrics are available:

[image]

**Good article to read:**

- [Deep Dive into Thanos-Part II](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/deep-dive-into-thanos-part-ii-8f48b8bba132)

Comment: Super awesome. I would have marked this as the accepted answer 1000 times if there was an option like that.

Comment: awesome, thanks. Why can't their docs be as clear as this :)

Comment: sidecarsService: "prometheus-kube-prometheus-thanos-discovery" where can i find side car service name ? do i need to change thanos sidecar  pod name? Im getting this error.level=error ts=2023-04-04T05:20:14.02297105Z caller=resolver.go:99 msg="failed to lookup SRV records" host=_grpc._tcp.kube-prometheus-kube-prome-prometheus-thanos-discovery.monitoring.svc.cluster.local err="no such host"

Answer (score 0):

Yuo don't need to change thanos sidecar pod name.
You can find the prometheus-kube-prometheus-thanos-discovery in the namespace you installed prometheus. For example, if you installed in **monitoring** namespace, run **kubectl get svc -n monitoring**.
Also ensure that you have specified the correct namespace under the sidecarsNamespce field in the thanos helm values file.